# In wsl under windows installe ubuntu followed the steps but gnome is not loading

Tags: gnome

Installed ubuntu under windows using wsl administrator command prompt (without any release option so I got version which is by default and I think ie 7~22.04.2)

followed all steps but i am not getting gnome screen

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Please focus on one topic per question, and be as specific as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Which steps did you follow? Please edit your question and add the link.